# Reading an ActionScript Dictionary object as a FREObject?

Tags: java, air

For an ANE I am writing, I have a flash.utils.Dictionary object I would like to pass to native Java code.

The Java call takes in FREObject[] args, so I would get the Dictionary as a FREObject. Is it possible for me to read a FREOBject of a dictionary and convert it into a Java equivalent?